# Can't find forms inside a html code - Web Scraping with Python and Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, forms, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrap [this website](http://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/informar/sistema-reune.htm), but there are some forms to fill.

The mainly objective is to fill these 5 forms (one appears after selecting another) and download the data through the button "Consultar".

This forms are coded in javascript and I can't find them in the page's html code. When I inspect the frames trough Google Chrome, I find the forms ID's, but the code doesn't find them.

I have just a prototype of my code. I can't advance without knowing what I can do to find these forms.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import os

#Variables

url = 'http://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/informar/sistema-reune.htm'
path_phantom = 'C:\\Users\\TBMEPYG\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe'

#Processing

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path= path_phantom)

driver.get(url)

data = driver.find_element_by_id('data_ref')

data.send_keys("21/08/2017")

driver.quit()
```

Edit:

I updated the code to this:

```
    from selenium import webdriver

    path_phantom = 'C:\\Users\\TBMEPYG\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe'
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path= path_phantom)
    driver.get('http://www.anbima.com.br/reune/reune.asp')


    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@class="full"]'))
    data = driver.find_element_by_name('Dt_Ref')
    data.clear()
    data.send_keys('21/08/
```

And I got this error:

```
CD: C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3
Current directory: C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3
python "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\Desktop\vamo.py"
Process started >>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\Desktop\vamo.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = driver.find_element_by_name('Dt_Ref')
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 426, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 832, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with name 'Dt_Ref'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"89","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:62040","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"name\", \"value\": \"Dt_Ref\", \"sessionId\": \"bdd3fc70-8dd0-11e7-aeb1-85b8cfbe0d1c\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/bdd3fc70-8dd0-11e7-aeb1-85b8cfbe0d1c/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Edit2:

Another possibility is to use the link inside of the the mains page http://www.anbima.com.br/reune/reune.asp

When I changed the code to this, I've got another error

```
from selenium import webdriver

path_phantom = 'C:\\Users\\TBMEPYG\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path= path_phantom)
driver.get('http://www.anbima.com.br/reune/reune.asp')


data = driver.find_element_by_name('Dt_Ref')
data.clear()
data.send_keys('21/08/2017')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\Desktop\vamo.py", line 9, in <module>
    data = driver.find_element_by_name('Dt_Ref')
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 426, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 832, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: {"request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"89","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:61820","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"name\", \"value\": \"Dt_Ref\", \"sessionId\": \"e61dd170-8dcf-11e7-a019-41573671066b\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/e61dd170-8dcf-11e7-a019-41573671066b/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Comment: It's not a form, it's a table

Comment: @Hackerman Any idea about how can I interact with this table? Inspecting the elements made me believe that all of them are forms, but I'm really new in the javascript world.

Comment: Try with, `data = driver.find_element_by_name('Dt_Ref')`

Comment: @Hackerman I've already done that. I believe that I'm missing something in the html code, because dt_ref doesn't appear there, only in the chrome's inspection. Following your advice I've got this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with name 'dt_ref'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to handle elements inside `form` you need to switch to `iframe` first:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@class="full"]'))
data = driver.find_element_by_name('Dt_Ref')
data.clear()
data.send_keys('21/08/2017')
```

Comment: I believe i've solved this step by another way. I found the "second page" http://www.anbima.com.br/reune/reune.asp but still can't scrap the Dt_Ref element. When i check the html of this link, all the information are there, but I cant scrap it. The error that was shown before is because the driver can't find the element, but now this is the error: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverExceptio

Comment: My code works on both pages (on second without switching) for me. Can you share the complete exception log?

Comment: Sure. I edited the question because the error is too long to post on comments.

Comment: Are you sure that [this](http://pythonscraping.com/pages/files/form.html) is exact page you want to handle? It seem to be some test page... there is no iframes on that page

Comment: Sorry. I added the wrong page. That's what I was practicing.

Comment: I updated the question, now is the right codes but with errors.

Comment: This seem to be PhantomJS issue. Is it mandatory to use headless browser? In Chrome solution works fine...

Comment: I has. I'm working under a bank proxy. It has to be a headless browser and I can download ChromeDriver under my network.

Comment: I think it could be a nodes problem. I Can't map the element because it is under another element. Makes sense? Have you tried your code in phantomJS?

Comment: I tried it with PhantomJS and got the same exception. It doesn't seem to be overlapped by another element. Also I made a screenshot and it looks ok. PhantomJS is not much reliable and has a lot of issues, so it's better just not to use it... You can try to use [headless Chrome](https://duo.com/blog/driving-headless-chrome-with-python) instead

Answer (score 0):

Just to update:

Problem not solved, but I know what is.

It's a bug in phantomJS that is occurring. So, if you have the same problem, try to use Chrome or Firefox.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I'd say your question is pretty much resolved then.  You should mark Andersson's answer as the accepted solution as he helped bug test it for you and try the headless chrome link he provided.

Answer (score -1):

I think you messed up with single and double quotes. Correct code would be-

```
driver.get("http://www.anbima.com.br/reune/reune.asp")
data = driver.find_element_by_name("Dt_Ref")
data.clear()
data.send_keys("21/08/2017")
```

Comment: How can it solve the issue? In Python there is no matter whether you use single or double quotes